# Finding the maximum elements whose sum is less than a given value in PyTorch

Tags: pytorch

Given any PyTorch 2D tensor, what will be the most efficient way to compute the number of top-K values for each row whose sum is less than a given value?

Input:

```
tensor([[0.6607, 0.1165, 0.0278, 0.1950],
        [0.0529, 0.4607, 0.2729, 0.2135],
        [0.3267, 0.0902, 0.4578, 0.1253]])
```

Required Output for the given value `0.8`:

```
tensor([[1], #as 0.6607+0.1950 > 0.8
        [2], #as 0.4607+0.2729+0.2135 > 0.8
        [2]]) #as 0.4578+0.3267+0.1253 > 0.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manage such operation by using a combination of sorting, cumulative sum, and max pooling.

First sort the values by row with [`torch.Tensor.sort`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.sort.html)

```
>>> v = x.sort(dim=1, descending=True).values
tensor([[0.6607, 0.1950, 0.1165, 0.0278],
        [0.4607, 0.2729, 0.2135, 0.0529],
        [0.4578, 0.3267, 0.1253, 0.0902]])
```

Then construct a mask on the cumulative sorted values that you get from applying [`torch.cumsum`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cumsum.html):

```
>>> torch.cumsum(v, dim=1) > .8
tensor([[False,  True,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True],
        [False, False,  True,  True]])
```

Applying a [`torch.Tensor.max`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html) on that mask will return the index of the first occurring `True` value, *i.e.* the location of the cumulative element which is above the threshold value `0.8`:

```
>>> mask.max(1, True).indices
tensor([[1],
        [2],
        [2]])
```